# What is the spectral norm of a random projection times a diagonal?

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, random-matrices, measure-concentration

Take $n\ll N$. Let $P$ be an $n\times N$ matrix of iid $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ random variables, and let $D$ be an $N\times N$ diagonal matrix.

What can be said about the distribution of the largest singular value of $PD$?

When $n=1$, I get concentration inequalities from Lemma 1 of [this paper](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-statistics/volume-28/issue-5/Adaptive-estimation-of-a-quadratic-functional-by-model-selection/10.1214/aos/1015957395.full). I would like a probabilistic upper bound for the general case, and I wouldn't be surprised if this is already available in the literature.

Answer (score 4):

I think the following answers your question (and more):
http://www-personal.umich.edu/~romanv/papers/product-random-deterministic.pdf

Comment: As the link of Ofer is now long broken, let me add that he was probably linking to a paper of Roman Vershynin entitled "Spectral norm of products of random and deterministic matrices". It can be found on the web, but I will not offer a link as this is apparently pointless.